# Dynamic access to variable from another namespace in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I get dynamic acces to variable from another namespace?

```
public namespace myNamespace = "http://example.com/mypackage/";

...

public var _publicVar: String = "foo";
myNamespace var  _namespaceVar: String = "bar";

...

trace(_publicVar);
trace(myNamespace::_namespaceVar);
trace(this["_publicVar"]);
trace(this["_namespaceVar"]); // <<< Exception
```

I can see this variable wthen I call describeType() and think it's possible

```
<variable name="_namespaceVar" type="String" uri="http://example.com/mypackage/">
...
</variable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use namespace myNamespace;
trace(this["_namespaceVar"]);
```

Comment: Oh! Amazing!
And as I understand I can not make a generic class that can get access to all the namespaces.

Like

     this [ "http://example.com/mypackage/_namespaceVar"]
or
     this [ "myNamespace :: _ namespaceVar"]

Comment: Not that I know of a way to do so.